# formatting a php variable into a web address

Tags: php, image, web

can you guys help me out with this, it should be easy but after 6 hours of work its frying my brain.

```
echo '<img src="', $webadd['data']['0']['address'], '"/>;
```

I just want it to be like:

```
<img src="http://www.image.com" />
```

the variable in the middle is the web address.

Comment: echo your `$webadd['data']['0']['address']`

Comment: What's the result? How is it not working?

Comment: you cannot concatenate string with commas

Comment: echo is working with commas.

Comment: @Arnaldo, you can pass multiple arguments to echo, commas work there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo '<img src="'.$webadd['data']['0']['address'].'"/>';
```

Comment: @AJStyles remember to accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the up and down arrows.

Comment: @Martin Kabanen : you should explain what was wrong in his code so that he can understands his mistake  :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed . by ,
**Try this:**

```
echo '<img src="'. $webadd['data']['0']['address'].'"/>;
```

or

```
echo "<img src=".'{$webadd['data']['0']['address']}'."/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<img src='{$webadd['data']['0']['address']}'/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
echo '<img src="' . $webadd['data']['0']['address'] . '" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo "<img src=\"" . $webadd['data']['0']['address'] . "\" />";`

Consider adding spaces around the dots for readability.

Answer (score 0):

TC lost to add qoutes to the end. Its works fine http://3v4l.org/5JCNc :)

```
$webadd['data']['0']['address'] = 'http://www.image.com';
echo '<img src="',$webadd['data']['0']['address'],'"/>';
```

See Example #1(separate by commas) from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php.